# How to load csv file from s3 bucket using C# and MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-s3

I want to load CSV file to MySql database table using a file from s3 bucket. I am able to load the file from the local drive using the following code

```
                using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Database = aaaa; Uid = bbbb; Pwd = ccc"))
                {

                MySqlBulkLoader loader = new MySqlBulkLoader(myConn);
                loader.TableName = "mytable";
                loader.FieldTerminator = "|";
                loader.LineTerminator = "\n";
                loader.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 2;
                loader.FileName = "c:\file1.csv";

                myConn.Open();
                int insertCount = bulkLoader.Load();
                myConn.Close();

            }
```

Can you pleas provide some example to load the csv file from s3 bucket? Thank you.

Comment: My approach: find out if `MySqlBulkLoader` can accept a `Stream` instead of a filename. Assuming it can, open a `Stream` from the S3 storage object and pass it to the loader. If that isn't possible, download the CSV file from S3 to a local file, and then pass that local file to the loader, and then clean up that local file when done.

Comment: and if you download the csv file to your local drive?

Comment: I will try stream option, but I want to load it from the s3 bucket

Comment: @akabaka Could you explain a bit more what you mean by "want it load it from the S3 bucket"? Are you saying you want it to go 'directly' from the file to the db table somehow? Diplomacy's suggestion of reading the file as a stream and passing it through to the BulkLoader is basically as close as you can get to that - the file data is going to have to 'pass through' your code one way or another.

Comment: @Kayndaar, I want to load the csv file  data to mysql db using either stream or by passing the bucket file name to bulk insert, but I am not sure, how can I pass stream to bulk insert

Comment: @akabaka @DiplomacyNotWar the `MySqlBulkLoader.SourceStream` property can be used to load directly from a `Stream`. (Note that you can't make the MySQL Server pull the file directly from S3; it will be "proxied" through your .NET application code: `MySqlBulkLoader` will do the work of downloading the file from S3 then uploading it to MySQL.)

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Ah there is an option for streams then. I did think that seemed likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3://db-bucket-name/folder-name/test.csv' INTO TABLE table-name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"+'"'+"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';